# Bashrc PS1 error

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

I created a nice `PS1` for bash with http://bashrcgenerator.com/, but something seems to go wrong. The terminal emulator shows me some random, characters which means that `PS1` probably has a syntax error. The weird thing is that it will work after I edit it (with nano). If I add a space, remove it, save it, and run bash, it works fine. But when I log out and log in agai,n it's buggy and weird again. This is my .bashrc:

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'

#PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
PS1="\[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;14m\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;15m \[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;10m\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;15m \
\[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;14m\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]\033[38;5;15m\033[38;5;15m \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Comment: Is that your entry for the 2015 International Obfuscated Shell Code Contest (IOSCC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend just manually creating the prompt yourself.  All you have to do is set up a few variables, and then your code for setting the prompt becomes readable.  In my bashrc file, I have this:

```
#Set variables for foreground colors
fgRed=$(tput setaf 1)     ; fgGreen=$(tput setaf 2)  ; fgBlue=$(tput setaf 4)
fgMagenta=$(tput setaf 5) ; fgYellow=$(tput setaf 3) ; fgCyan=$(tput setaf 6)
fgWhite=$(tput setaf 7)   ; fgBlack=$(tput setaf 0)
#Set variables for background colors
bgRed=$(tput setab 1)     ; bgGreen=$(tput setab 2)  ; bgBlue=$(tput setab 4)
bgMagenta=$(tput setab 5) ; bgYellow=$(tput setab 3) ; bgCyan=$(tput setab 6)
bgWhite=$(tput setab 7)   ; bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
#Set variables for font weight and text decoration
B=$(tput bold) ; U=$(tput smul) ; C=$(tput sgr0)
#NOTE: ${C} clears the current formatting

PS1="${B}${fgCyan}\u${C}@\h(bash): ${fgGreen}\w${C} > "
```

I'll bet you can tell at a quick glance what my prompt looks like.  And that's the point; no fancy WYSIWYG editors are required.

The reason I use [`tput`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput) is that it's supposed to be more portable.  And as an added bonus, using `tput` makes it so that when you type `echo $PS1` at the command prompt, it'll show you a formatted/colorized version of `PS1`.

This doesn't exactly answer why yours isn't working.  But if you set up your prompt like this, you will definitely be able to get rid of that pesky error.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. Writing it myself is much cleaner than that unreadable WYSIWYG thing anyway. I was just trying (and failing) to be lazy.